# Interesting Maxima confusion

Tags: maxima

I recently coded a function in Maxima and got unexpected result.
What is -1^n for n=0?

I tried He(n,x := expand((-1^n)*exp(x^2/2)*diff(exp(-x^2/2),x,n)); as exactly shown for Hermite polynomials on Wikipedia.  Then looked at He(0,x) and got -1.  Hmmm.  Should be 1.  Then tried (-1^0); as coded in the function above and (-1)^n; to get -1 and 1.  This seems odd.  Do you need this much tightness?

Comment: Evidently the `^` operator has higher precedence than unary minus. It doesn't seem odd to me.

Comment: Yep:  https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_35.html

Comment: Just caught me by surprise.  Ingrained to think of simply a constant.